# Stop Windows 10 search from running commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, group-policy

We disable the run box on our network through a GPO which for anything upto 10 stopped you browsing to UNC paths or running commands of any kind. In 10 it has the same effect **UNLESS** you use the search box on the task bar to search for a UNC path or command it offer to run it as shown in the image.

[image]

This bypasses the policy and lets users access commands they shouldn't.

I can't find a way to stop it, removing the search box still lets the user search by typing with the start menu open.

Anyone know how to stop it offering to run commands or browse to shares? I would be happy with restricting it to searching Programs only.

We have the following policies enabled:

User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove Run menu from Start Menu.

and

User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Prevent access to the command prompt

Comment: Which group policies specifically have you enabled?  I need to know this information in order to provide you a well researched answers.

Comment: Using the Run+Windows key and typing `control.exe srchadmin.dll` will allow you to allow what is shown in the index as far as shares that can solve that issue.

Comment: Whoever is running your network has a lot to learn. Our organization has disabled the Run dialog box as well. But guess what? There are a number of ways to do things. Users can create a shortcut by using the Menu Bar and going to File>New>Shortcut and type in the program name, including parameters. I do it all the time. This is a false security practice. Restricting the Run dialog does nothing. Blocking Start Menu entries does nothing. You need to restrict the program itself. A user could create a shortcut to any program they wanted, using any parameters. Use GPOs to block the program instead.

Comment: @Ramhound added.

Comment: I have long deleted the research I did.  So I won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

So I just realized this after looking at it.

You need to disable the RUN feature in the search index Via Group Policy.

**User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove Run menu from Start Menu.**

Then link the policy.

You can also prevent access from Command prompt being ran by the user.

**User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System**

In the right side pan choose. **Prevent access to the command prompt**
Double click and enable it.

Hope this helps.

Coratana or the Search index is using the **RUN** Feature to run these commands. Once the user types a command in **RUN** is is transferred to a Terminal and ran.

Comment: We already remove run from the start menu like this which isn't stopping the run commands from search as above. Preventing access to command prompt doesn't stop it either I can still run any command I want from the search box.

Answer (score 0):

The search service is based on the index. We could try to modify the indexing to change the search behavior(Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Indexing options).

If you want to disable the search feature completely, we could try to disable the Windows search service.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WSearch
Double click on Start and edit the value:

Change Startup type :

Automatic - 2

Manual - 3

Disabled - 4

Automatic (Delayed Start) - 2

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, just stops them searching for files.

Answer (score 0):

- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar-> Remove Run menu from Start Menu
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar-> Do not search communications - Enabled
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar-> Do not search files - Disabled
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar-> Do not search Internet - Enabled
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar-> Do not search programs and control panel items- Enabled
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar -> Do not use the search-based method when resolving shell shortcuts
- User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar -> Do not use the tracking-based method when resolving Shell shortcuts

If all of this fails, maybe you can prevent commands from executing if you exclude Windows Folder from indexing.